# Padding value between Flutter Appbar action items?

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout

I am using AppBar widget and custom Appbar using container and need to position trailing action items like appbar does. Otherwise when moving from Appbar to customAppbar using Container. It's totally different.

so what is the padding value between action items and how much padding between last action item and border.

Thanks.

Comment: If you add your current snippet as well as a demo of what you want to achieve, others can work on it and help you better.

Answer (score 0):

You can Simply use SizeBox() widget or Spacer() widget it's give you space between action items

Comment: No bro..that's not what I want

Answer (score 0):

You can read the Material 3 spec, Flutter uses mostly a small app bar, so you can read the paddings on the picture and implement them in Padding widgets around your icons. https://m3.material.io/components/top-app-bar/specs#14e23895-ac2e-40d8-b0f7-8d016c10a225